# Suppress of detail section is not working

Tags: csv, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report and i suppressed its detail section by putting formula in Section Expert -> Suppress(No drill down) as

```
EvaluateAfter ({@dtls})
Shared sValues as String

If {@sValues} = ""Then ` 
    true
else
   false
end if
```

But its not working.

I tried with checked Suppress Blank Section but nothing seems working. My detail section is not getting suppress and i am getting a blank line[in detail section] between header and footer.

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried many solutions provided over internet but not get my problem resolved so i am posting here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think instead of this `{@sValues}` you need to just use `sValues`.. Also I have a doubt whether this formula complied? are you using C# coding or crystal reports as a standalone application? And whether this is a crystal syntax or basic syntax?

Comment: i am using c# coding. I am using crystal report 2008 and exporting it to CSV format.

Comment: Is issue resolved?

Comment: Nope.. still struggling :(

Comment: Ok what does that @sValue contain...try to check that first..may be you are not getting null in that form7la